# Game Design Patterns ( think GOF ) literature?

Tags: software-engineering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some programming design patterns that are useful in game development?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4157/what-are-some-programming-design-patterns-that-are-useful-in-game-development)

Is there any literature on game design patterns? I'm taking a software design class and would like to learn how some of these design patterns would apply to game development.

Comment: Very similar to [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4157/what-are-some-programming-design-patterns-that-are-useful-in-game-development) which has some great answers.