# Is HTML5 and Canvas good for rapid prototyping of games?

Tags: html5, prototyping

Are there frameworks and processes for HTMl5 that can be used for the rapid prototyping of 2D games?

Answer (score 6):

I built http://gamejs.org partly for this purpose. It follows the PyGame API which I know is sometimes used for prototyping.

I would argue that JavaScript lends itself very well to writing game code quickly; for a more elaborate argument to this effect see [Capitalizing on JavaScript's prototypal inheritance](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9850/capitalizing-on-javascripts-prototypal-inheritance/9862)

Other advantages if you stay with simple technologies, like html5 & js:

- every computer has an interpreter and a debugger for JS installed (even mobile devices)
- easy to pickup for newcomers
- well documented language, still evolving
- open technologies through & through

Whether html5 is more suitable than, say, Flash or even pen&paper depends on your game and how evolved your concept is.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [PixieEngine](http://pixieengine.com). It's a web based game development IDE that lets you develop and publish games without having to download or set up a development environment.

[image: PixieEngine IDE screenshot]

The advantages over plain HTML Canvas and JavaScript are that CoffeeScript is a very syntax light language, and the built in libraries optimize specifically for the prototyping of games.

For example in HTML Canvas when you want to fill a circle you need to call:

```
context.fillStyle = color
context.beginPath()
context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.TAU, true)
context.closePath()
context.fill()
```

But the PixieEngine canvas wrapper provides a simple method

```
canvas.fillCircle(x, y, radius, color)
```

HTML Canvas and JavaScript are good for rapid game prototyping, but [PixieEngine](http://pixieengine.com) is much better.

Answer (score 3):

Well, a cursory Google search produces several results:

- [Isogenic Engine](http://www.isogenicengine.com/)
- [Akihabara](http://www.kesiev.com/akihabara/)
- [Impact](http://impactjs.com/)
- [LimeJS](http://www.limejs.com/)

I don't know anything about them specifically, but I would think that in general HTML5 is probably a decent way to prototype games even without a framework or engine: quick, direct, low overhead and easy to iterate on.

Answer (score 3):

Yes!  I'm part of the 2 man team that builds [Construct 2, the HTML5 game creator](http://www.scirra.com).

Our tool is popular for building full games and also amongst an audience who wish to rapidly prototype games and ideas.

When creating a prototype anything that can save you time is beneficial and we've worked hard to make Construct 2 a powerful time saving device as well.  [Results can be created in minutes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RlSmkSbleI).