# The most popular pattern for game-related programming in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, patterns

As the title says, what are the most popular design solutions when creating a new game or a new game engine?

Comment: This question is a poll question. You're asking people's opinions on what is "popular." That's not what this site is here for.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think he meant common, not popular. I would like to edit it but im not entirely sure.

Comment: @Sidar: Common is no better than popular; they're both poll questions asking for opinions. They're not good subjective, so it doesn't belong here.

Comment: @Sidar this is the meaning of my question, if it's misleading feel free to edit.

Comment: @NicolBolas I strongly disagree. Design patterns that are recurring in almost every project is not the same as "What do you think is best". He is not asking for an opinion, he is asking what is commonly used in game projects. I gave him a list of answers below. Nowhere did I ever said these are THE ones. It's up for him to decide what fits best for him. I'm not denying it's pretty ambiguous.

Comment: @Sidar: And that's exactly why this question is not constructive. A good question has a *concrete* answer. An answer is *supposed* to be "THE" answer. It should not be many answers all saying different things, leaving it up to the OP to decide who's "right", but nobody being right in an objectively determinable sense. That doesn't help anyone except the OP. And that's not what the SE model is about. It's about helping people who find the information later. Knowing what the OP decided was the best answer is useless to them. That's why poll questions are supposed to be closed.

Comment: @NicolBolas I didn't exactly gave him an answer that would lead him to decide which answer is right. His question is answerable. It just so happens that you can't answer in full. In fact I gave him a link to a list of design patterns that work for gamedevelopment. In fact that alone gave him his answer. Sure there is more design patterns that are used. However the most common ones seem to be listed in that link.

Comment: @Sidar: "It just so happens that you can't answer in full." Therefore, it cannot be answered. And links are not answers; if an answer can't stand alone, it should be a comment.

Comment: @NicoleBolas "Therefore, it cannot be answered." It still satisfies apparently. Ill leave it at that.

Comment: @Sidar: The question is 1 hour old and has 3 close votes. And 3 downvotes.

Comment: @NicolBolas Even so I still don't agree with your "Common is no better than popular". My list does answer his question for a great part. It's just that there are far more design patterns and I can't list them all. It's not exactly fair to say his question is not valid because people say it's not constructive. I don't see a poll question. But whatever, so be it then. ( I'm not trying to win his vote, I simply just disagree with the fuss being made)

Comment: This question doesn't deserve closing. It's a very common mistake among beginning game programmer to assume that design patterns will solve everything. They need to see further than that.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4157/what-are-some-programming-design-patterns-that-are-useful-in-game-development

Comment: Oh, now this changes everything, removed my answer and moved the juicy part to this other question.

Answer (score 1):

Patterns were designed to solve a certain problems within a/several domain(s). There are tons of design patterns for games. There is even the possibility that you might come up with your own! ( Well that depends on how much of problem solver you are ).

Allot of articles on creating games implicitly show you certain design patterns.

But ...hey google is your friend.
[Here](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/)

These are pretty much common
Prototype
Singleton
Flyweight
Command
Observer
State
Abstract Factory
Factory
Object Pool

But there are so many others that apply as well.

I think the reason you got a downvote is because it's too hard to give you an exact answer. It really depends on what your game specifics are.

edit:
Also I agree with lorancou. Don't try to hammer on design patterns. There are other solutions to any problem.

Comment: Just today i learned about this Factory and Abstract Factory pattern and i end up saying "no way to adopt this for a game", the funny thing is that now is on the most wanted list :D . I would like to see an example of that because i noticed that adding a new product in this Abstract Factory it's not that simple .

Comment: Abstract Factory is quite simple.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8_wwa90tzM&feature=plcp . Yes this is in Flash. But the concept applies to any kind of language with interfaces/Abstract classes.

Comment: no doubt about that, but i'm not convinced about this for a larger and more "dynamic" use when you have to introduce new object definitions and in general new "products", i was looking for a large project or for a demonstration that can prove that i'm wrong thinking about this as a bad solution.

Comment: That won't really do you any good. When you work on a project you will walk into a problem that needs a solution. This is where Design patterns come in. It's up to you what you use and how you implement them. If you think you know a better way, go for it.